# How do I specify CSS cell padding for multiple tables?

Tags: css, padding, css-tables

I have two (maybe three or more) tables on a page and I want table A to have cell padding 10px, table B to have padding 20px.  Making a CSS td element such as `{padding: 10px;}` is no good because both tables would be 10px.  And I don't want to have to put `class="diffpad"` on every single `<td>` of the second table.  Basically, I want to specify one padding for all the cells of one table, and a different padding size for all the cells of a second table.  But, as you know, you can't add the padding style to a table element.  So how do you do it without repeating yourself a million times for each and every `<td>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving unique id to each of the tables (not tds) and you can do this.

```
#table1 td{
    padding:10px;
}
#table2 td{
    padding:20px;
}
```